# How to swap two characters in a string?

Tags: string, rust

I want to write a function as follows:

- Input: String A, int i, 0 < i < len(A)
- Output: String A with character at (i - 1) swapped with character at i.

What is a *clean* solution that will achieve this? My current solution is:

```
let mut swapped = input_str[0..i].to_string();
swapped.push(input_str.char_at(i));
swapped.push(input_str.char_at(i - 1));
swapped.push_str(&query[i..input_str.len()]);
```

But that only works for ASCII strings. I can think of other solutions as converting to a vector in UTF-32, swapping there and converting back to a string, but it seems like a lot of extra work.

Comment: I think there's a mistake in your code -- if I read it correctly, it pushes the characters at `i` and `i - 1` twice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a pretty solution:

```
use std::str::CharRange;

fn swap_chars_at(input_str: &str, i: usize) -> String {
    // Pre-allocate a string of the correct size
    let mut swapped = String::with_capacity(input_str.len());
    // Pluck the previous character
    let CharRange { ch: prev_ch, next: prev } = input_str.char_range_at_reverse(i);
    // Pluck the current character
    let CharRange { ch, next } = input_str.char_range_at(i);
    // Put them back
    swapped.push_str(&input_str[..prev]);
    swapped.push(ch);
    swapped.push(prev_ch);
    swapped.push_str(&input_str[next..]);
    // Done!
    swapped
}

#[test]
fn smoke_test() {
    let s = swap_chars_at("lyra", 2);
    assert_eq!(s, "lrya");
}

#[test]
fn unicode() {
    // 'ç' takes up 2 bytes in UTF-8
    let s = swap_chars_at("ça va?", 2);
    assert_eq!(s, "aç va?");
}
```

From the [documentation](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.StrExt.html#tymethod.char_range_at):

- `fn char_range_at(&self, start: usize) -> CharRange`

  - Pluck a character out of a string and return the index of the next character.
- `fn char_range_at_reverse(&self, start: usize) -> CharRange`

  - Given a byte position and a str, return the previous char and its position.

Together, these two methods let us peek backwards and forwards in the string—which is exactly what we want.

---

But wait, there's more! DK pointed out a corner case with the above code. If the input contains any [*combining characters*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character), they may become separated from the characters they combine with.

Now, this question is about Rust, not Unicode, so I won't go into the details of [how exactly that works](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Grapheme_Cluster_Boundaries). All you need to know for now is that Rust provides [this method](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.StrExt.html#tymethod.grapheme_indices):

- `fn grapheme_indices(&self, is_extended: bool) -> GraphemeIndices`

  - Returns an iterator over the [grapheme clusters](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Grapheme_Cluster_Boundaries) of self and their byte offsets.

With a healthy application of `.find()` and `.rev()`, we arrive at this (hopefully) correct solution:

```
#![allow(unstable)]  // `GraphemeIndices` is unstable

fn swap_graphemes_at(input_str: &str, i: usize) -> String {
    // Pre-allocate a string of the correct size
    let mut swapped = String::with_capacity(input_str.len());
    // Find the grapheme at index i
    let (_, gr) = input_str.grapheme_indices(true)
        .find(|&(index, _)| index == i)
        .expect("index does not point to a valid grapheme");
    // Find the grapheme just before it
    let (prev, prev_gr) = input_str.grapheme_indices(true).rev()
        .find(|&(index, _)| index < i)
        .expect("no graphemes to swap with");
    // Put it all back together
    swapped.push_str(&input_str[..prev]);
    swapped.push_str(gr);
    swapped.push_str(prev_gr);
    swapped.push_str(&input_str[i+gr.len()..]);
    // Done!
    swapped
}

#[test]
fn combining() {
    // Ensure that "c\u{327}" is treated as a single unit
    let s = swap_graphemes_at("c\u{327}a va?", 3);
    assert_eq!(s, "ac\u{327} va?");
}
```

Admittedly it's a bit convoluted. First it iterates through the input, plucking out the grapheme cluster at `i`. Then it iterates *backward* ([`.rev()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IteratorExt.html#tymethod.rev)) through the input, picking the rightmost cluster with index `< i` (i.e. the previous cluster). Finally it goes and puts everything back together.

If you're being *really* pedantic, there are still more special cases to deal with. For example, if the string contains Windows newlines (`"\r\n"`), then we probably don't want to swap them around. And in Greek, the letter sigma (σ) is written differently when it's at the end of a word (ς), so a better algorithm should translate between them as necessary. And don't forget those [bidirectional control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bi-directional_text#Unicode)...

But for the sake of our sanity, we'll stop here.

Comment: I don't believe this is correct: you're dealing with codepoints, not graphemes, which is what you *should* be.  That is, if you have combining code points, they won't get swapped with the code point you're swapping.

Comment: @DK Good point. I was going to say the standard library doesn't have a grapheme splitter, but it turns out it does. Noted and edited.

Comment: Impressive edit.  The *real* problem here is that the original question is completely wrong-headed: if you're ever doing anything that relies on a concrete concept of a "character", you're probably just causing trouble for yourself.  Getting it right is incredibly difficult.

Answer (score 0):

building the *char-switched* string from scratch:

```
fn swap_chars_at(idx: usize, s: &str) -> String {
    let mut rslt = "".to_string();
    let mut rm = '\0';
    for (i, c) in s.chars().enumerate() {
        if idx == i {
            rm = c;
        } else {
            rslt.push(c);
            if idx + 1 == i {
                rslt.push(rm);
            }
        }
    }
    rslt
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=877a43a803c0fbc1f0c3d8c26eb101c2)